# Why are HTML tables frowned upon?

Tags: html, xhtml, html-table

Is it just because some people think they are harder to read? I find it much easier to explain a layout to somebody by drawing a grid than by using floating divs. And if they are learning to code floating divs then they have to deal with the setting widths and using CSS clear.

(by the way, I don't use tables myself)

Comment: This discussion has already been had.  A lot.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tables+vs.+divs

Answer (score 9):

They violate semantics of what a table is. Tables should be used for tabular data. They also are quite heavy on markup. In addition, they lock your site into one structure to a specific grid.

Answer (score 3):

Tables are for storing tabular data. Content is not tabular data.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly a matter of separation of concerns - your HTML should be marking up your content, not decide on what the UI will look like and be layed-out, which is the concern of CSS.

Tables should be reserved for tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

This is taken from another site, but still just as relevant:

> 1. Tables are usually more bytes of markup. (Longer to download, and more
>      bytes of traffic for the host.)
> 2. Tables usually prevent incremental rendering. (Takes longer
>      for the user to see anything on the
>      page.)
> 3. Tables may require you to chop single, logical images into multiple
>      ones. (This makes redesigns total
>      hell, and also increases page load
>      time [more http requests and more
>      total bytes].)
> 4. Tables break text copying on some browsers. (That's annoying to the
>      user.)
> 5. Tables prevent certain layouts from working within them (like
>      height:100% for child elements of
>      ). (They limit what you can
>      actually do in terms of layout.)
> 6. Once you know CSS, table-based layouts usually take more time to
>      implement. (A little effort up-front
>      learning CSS pays off heavily in the
>      end.)
> 7. Tables are semantically incorrect markup for layout. (They
>      describe the presentation, not the
>      content.)
> 8. Tables make life hell for those using screen readers. (Not only do you
>      get the other benefits of CSS, you're
>      also helping out the
>      blind/partially-sighted. This is a
>      Good Thing.)
> 9. Tables lock you into the current design and make redesigns MUCH harder
>      than semantic HTML+CSS. (Have you seen
>      CSS Zen Garden?)

**SAUCE:** http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html

Comment: If it's taken from an other site then you should at least credit them with a link...

Answer (score 1):

Its mainly a hype. Tables are an acceptable way and often more logically way of separating a view into multiple sections. However CSS is more dynamic, if you go with tables you're often stuck with them especially since tables are often placed in between 'the data' while css is defined externally. Also changing a 'table-like' layout made in css is easier than changing a table made layout.

On the internet there are a couple of good resources about this question:

http://www.decloak.com/dev/csstables/css_tables_01.aspx

http://iamelgringo.blogspot.com/2009/02/tables-vs-css-css-trolls-begone.html

As you can see it's also often a semantics thing. Semantically a table is not ment for layouts, (however it sure is handy and these kind of distinctions are more for purists).

Comment: that's the thing, it's NOT more logical, it's more logical to use CSS for layout and to use tables for TABULAR data. It can be done, but it's not recommended because of any of the above answers

Comment: Ah I meant logical as in: as a person a table is a logical way to structure data. It's easy to see in your head. While floating divs are hard to see in your head (and sometimes differ even in browser implementations or when a user resizes the screen). (That's why I upped Oded's comment, he's right on the money. However the frowning on 'table' for layout sometimes has it's uses, that's why I layed out a few pros and cons.

I do agree though that usually it's better to use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not every browser displays them the same way... should only be for tabular data, not content